# Android ImageView duplicated content LazyLoad

Tags: android, imageview, lazy-loading

I have problem with lazy loading images to ImageViews. When i scroll down, i see images from top (dupliacated), when new image is downloaded its replaced with new one. How can i show on new images ProgressBar, and replace it with images when its downloaded?

Here is my getView() from LazyAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
    return vi;
}
```

and item.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar android:layout_width="75dp"
                 android:layout_height="75dp"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:minHeight="300px"
    />
  </FrameLayout>
```

imageLoader.DisplayImage its asyncTask.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the image path to tags for ImageView.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setTag(data[position]);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
    return vi;
}
```

Comment: Its not working :( before download, i see duplicated images from top

Comment: Maybe he should have mentioned to use the image path stored in the tag as well?